# Can't move Jsreport files since utilizing azure-storage for persistence

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-storage, persistence, jsreport

I recently updated my kubernetes deployed docker container of jsreport to use an azure-storage container for persistent storage. It effectively loads and saves files to the storage account as I create them. However, when ever I move a file in the portal to a folder, or move a folder into another folder, it hangs and crashes the instance completely. I noticed in the storage container, it creates a ~.tran folder and file. However, when I restart the instance, it does not load from the ~.tran folder, and that folder remains. While that folder exists, I can't run any templates or create new ones, let alone move any. Once I remove the folder and restart, I can create and run templates again, but if I try to move anything to a folder, the problem repeats itself. Please help! Persisting with azure is making jsreport unusable.

I tried redeploying the container, deleting the ~.tran file, changed storage network to allow all. I expected this to be a small bug, but now I think it may be an issue with how azure-storage fundamentally communicates with jsreport as folders in this storage container itself can't easily be moved